# Where can I find more information on AES mode SIC?

Tags: dart, encryption, aes

SIC is the default mode provided by the Dart encrypt package, although none of the resources I have looked into go into details of the benefits/drawbacks of SIC mode. [Here](https://cryptography.fandom.com/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) says SIC mode is another name for CTR mode, although the Dart encrypt package has CTR mode independent of the default SIC mode. Any resources about SIC mode would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

SIC stands for *Segmented Integer Counter* and is another name for the CTR mode, described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)) in detail. In the *Note* section at the beginning, explicit reference is made to the equivalence of CTR and SIC.

---

The [*encrypted*](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) library is a wrapper for some functionality of the [*PointyCastle*](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle) library, which in turn is modeled after the [*BouncyCastle*](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) library.

From the documentation of the *BouncyCastle* library for [`SICBlockCipher`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/modes/SICBlockCipher.html):

> `Class SICBlockCipher` ...
> Implements the Segmented Integer Counter
> (SIC) mode on top of a simple block cipher. This mode is also known as
> CTR mode.

This relation is reflected in the implementation. The PointyCastle library implements CTR as derivation of SIC, s. [`CTRStreamCipher`](https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart/blob/master/lib/stream/ctr.dart#L10):

> /// Just an alias to be able to create SIC as CTR
> `class CTRStreamCipher extends SICStreamCipher {...`

---

For completeness: *PointyCastle* implements CTR and SIC not only as stream ciphers, but also as block ciphers, e.g. [`CTRBlockCipher`](https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart/blob/master/lib/block/modes/ctr.dart). However, the block ciphers are based on the stream ciphers, so again the CTR mode is derived from the SIC mode.